# Using LEFT JOIN with 2 different query GROUP BY

Tags: php, sql, count, group-by

My first SQL query is:

```
SELECT username,COUNT(username) as total_active_users FROM users WHERE active = '1' GROUP BY referrer //  $act_user
```

To count the active users for each referrer

The second sql query is:

```
SELECT COUNT(orders) as total_user_orders FROM users_orders GROUP BY $act_user['username'] // the username from the first query.
```

To count total number of orders for each user which i got from the first query

What I'm trying to do it using `LEFT JOIN` to only count active users who have 1 order at least

The problem is: I have 2 different `GROUP BY` the first one is "referrer" and the second is "username"

I'm trying to do something like :

```
SELECT u.username, COUNT(u.username) as total_active_users, COUNT(b.orders) as 
total_user_orders FROM users u LEFT JOIN users_orders b on u.username = b.username
WHERE u.active = '1' AND total_user_orders >= '1' GROUP BY (u.referrer for u) and (b.username for b)
```

Any idea please?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this instead:

```
SELECT 
  a.username, 
  COUNT(u.username) as total_active_users, 
  COUNT(b.orders) as total_user_orders 
FROM
(
   SELECT username FROM users_orders WHERE total_user_orders >= '1' 
   UNION ALL
   SELECT username FROM users        WHERE u.active = '1' 
) AS a
LEFT JOIN users        AS u ON a.username = u.username
LEFT JOIN users_orders AS b on u.username = b.username
GROUP BY a.username;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that user names are unique and that for a user to have at least one order means the same as for them to have at least one row in the `users_orders` table, you could do the following:

```
SELECT
  u.referrer,
  COUNT(DISTINCT u.username) AS usercount
FROM users u
INNER JOIN users_orders uo ON u.username = uo.username
WHERE u.active = 1
;
```

The join between `users` and `users_orders` acts as a filter (in addition to that on the `active` status). It may produce duplicate user names but `COUNT(DISTINCT)` will count unique entries only.